# $ionicScrollDelegate.$getByHandle() not working. why?

Tags: angularjs, ionic-framework

I want to scroll an item to top of screen. when pressed on that item. i am using following code.

```
<ion-list id="iphoneTutorials-list2" ng-repeat="(f,chapter) in iphoneVideos">
      <ion-item style="border-left: none;border-right: none;border-top: none;" class="item-text-wrap" ng-click="toggledisplay($index)" delegate-handle="$index"><i class="icon ion-ios-arrow-right" ng-if="!trigger[$index]"></i>
     <i class="icon ion-ios-arrow-down" ng-if="trigger[$index]"></i> {{chapter.chapter_name}}</ion-item>
      <ion-list ng-show="trigger[$index]">
        <ion-item class="item-text-wrap" ng-click="openVideo(video.video_id,video.video_name,f,$index,video.Description)" style="margin-left: 10%;border-left: none;border-right: none;"  ng-repeat="video in chapter.chapter_content">{{video.video_name}}</ion-item>
      </ion-list>
```

and in controller i am using this:

```
$rootScope.toggledisplay = function(index){
    $timeout($ionicScrollDelegate.$getByHandle(index).scrollTop(),3000);
    if($rootScope.trigger[index]){
        $rootScope.trigger[index] = false;

    }
    else{
        $rootScope.trigger[index] = true;
    }
}
```

this the message i am getting in console:

```
ionic.bundle.js:26799 Delegate for handle "7" could not find a corresponding element with delegate-handle="7"! scrollTop() was not called!
Possible cause: If you are calling scrollTop() immediately, and your element with delegate-handle="7" is a child of your controller, then your element may not be compiled yet. Put a $timeout around your call to scrollTop() and try again.
```

Can any help me with my problem?

Comment: this is ionic v1 right?

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that $timeout expects a function as a first parameter and you are **executing** a function instead. You have to remove the parenthesis from the `scrollTop()` method:

```
$timeout($ionicScrollDelegate.$getByHandle(index).scrollTop,3000);
```

Now the function will execute after the `3000` ms and in the right context (where the handlers can be found)